# Knowledgebase / Docs: Custom Post Type, Pages or as a Post Category?

Tags: custom-post-types, documentation

I'm trying to decide on how to organize a new site/theme.

It has the standard sections: Home, About, Contact, Blog but also an (admin-only editable) Knowledgebase/Documentation area.

My first thought was to create a custom post type to separate out the documentation area but it could more easily be done as parent/child pages or even separated out by tag/category in the blog.

Just wondering if anyone has built something like this in the past.

Comment: I would use a custom post type - this is pretty much what they are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the following: `http://www.wpbundle.com/demo/knowledgebase/questions/`<sup>*)</sup>. To me it looks like only a clever combination of archive display.

<sup>You'll have to copy/paste the link to your browser as I don't link to commercial themes from inside answers.</sup>